# MVVM: Bind ListView.SelectedItem.Property to VM Property

Tags: wpf, listview, mvvm, binding

I am using the following ListView:

```
<ListView DataContext="{StaticResource mainViewModel}" ItemsSource="{Binding Items.View}" IsSynchronizedWithCurrentItem="True" SelectedItem="{Binding Path=CurrentFile, Source={StaticResource anotherViewModel}, Mode=OneWayToSource}">
    <ListView.View>
        <GridView>
            <GridViewColumn Header="File Path" DisplayMemberBinding="{Binding FilePath}" />
            <GridViewColumn Header="Creation" DisplayMemberBinding="{Binding CreationDate}" />
        </GridView>
    </ListView.View>
</ListView>
```

I am binding the ListView (of "File" objects) to one ViewModel and the SelectedItem to a "File" object on another ViewModel. This works fine but now I need to not bind the whole object, but one property. I.e. instead of something like `SelectedItem="{Binding Path=CurrentFile` I need `SelectedItem.FilePath="{Binding Path=FilePath`. Is this possible or does SelectedItem binding have to map to the same object type of the ListView collection?

Comment: what is your scenario? you are trying to accomplish something strange in my opinion.

Comment: True. I am loading a Windows Media Player based usercontrol with its own viewmodel based on the file selected. This control needs to be reusable so cannot be part of the mainViewModel. I could just do it in code behind but am trying to stick to patterns where possible.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`SelectedItem` must point to an object present in the `ItemsSource`. You need to look at `SelectedValue` and `SelectedValuePath` for your scenario.